# OSS-licenses : Getting java.io.FileNotFoundException: after running "clean"

Tags: android, kotlin

When using OSS-licenses plugin ("com.google.android.gms.oss-licenses-plugin"),

I'm getting *java.io.FileNotFoundException:  /build/generated/third_party_licenses/dependencies.json (No such file or directory)*

(Reproduced only in "clean" task)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following code (build.gradle) fixes the issue

```
tasks.licensesCleanUp.enabled = false
```